# Trying to hook into rest_insert_user to add extra meta data to new user

Tags: php, wordpress

Im using wp-rest-user to register a new user.  I want to add some meta data to the new user using the 'rest_insert_user' hook. but it doesnt seem to want to work.

```
add_action(  'rest_insert_user', 'addUserMeta', 10, 3);
function addUserMeta($user, $request, $isCreating)
{
      $id = $user->ID;
      if (!$isCreating) {
            add_user_meta($id, 'testKey', 'testmeta');
      } else {
            update_user_meta($id, 'testKey', 'testmeta');
      }
}
```

This is in my projects plugin script.

im simply trying to display all the data to test it

```
<?php
$users = get_users( );
foreach($users as $user){
      print_r(get_user_meta ( $user->ID));

echo '<br><br>';
}


?>
```

Any ideas why this wont work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you did, but your supplied code does add a meta when I tried...

Comment: Have you activate your plugin?

Comment: it did? thats great newws at least.  Yea the plugin is active.  so i guess theres something interfering with it somewhere down the line

Comment: is my  print_r(get_user_meta ( $user->ID)); showing you the test meta value? or am I testing that wrong

Comment: I only check the db, table `usermeta` has `testKey` entry in it...